# Discrepancy between Matlab del2 and Matlab gradient of gradient

Tags: matlab, image-processing, operators, gradient

can anyone explain why I get such dramatically different results for the Laplace operator in Matlab when I use

```
laplacian = del2(image);
```

versus

```
[x, y] = gradient(image);
[xx, xy] = gradient(x);
[yx, yy] = gradient(y);
laplacian = xx + yy;
```

Shouldn't these come to the same thing? They get particularly divergent when one includes a dx term.

Putting my example up here in case it helps: I have a test field consisting of

```
 [5; 2.5+2.5i; 5i; -2.5+2.5i; -5; -2.5-2.5i; -5i; 2.5-2.5i]
```

times its transpose (I can post the whole matrix if it helps). The inner block (3:6, 3:6) of the del2() of this field is:

```
[-2.5           -0.625-0.625i  -2.5i           0.625-0.625i ;
 -0.625+0.625i   0             -0.625+0.625i   0            ;
  2.5i          -0.625+0.625i  -2.5           -0.625+0.625i ;
  0.625+0.625i   0             -0.625+0.625i   0            ]
```

while the inner block (3:6, 3:6) of the xx + yy is:

```
[-5             -2.5-2.5i      -5i            -2.5-2.5i     ; 
 -2.5+2.5i      -2.5           -2.5-2.5i      -2.5i         ; 
  5i            -2.5+2.5i      -5             -2.5-2.5i     ; 
  2.5+2.5i       2.5i          -2.5+2.5i      -2.5          ]
```

which as you can see will make a dramatic difference in any further equations. Might anyone have an explanation, thanks very much!

Comment: What function is your variable 'image' representing?

Comment: It's an image loaded through imread().

Comment: Have you taken a look at the source code? "type del2", "type gradient"

Comment: They can both be brought into the editor as well. I could spend all day trying to pick apart the differences but thought someone might have a conceptual explanation.

Comment: what dramatic effects? please illustrate! I only got some distortion at the edges. function used to test: `z=X.^2.*Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at [Matlab's documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/), the laplacian of f at (x,y), del2(f(x,y)) is computed using only (x,y) and its nearest neighbours: x+1, x-1, y+1, y-1.

The same goes for the gradient function (and the divergence, which explicitly uses the gradient function). Computing the gradient twice involves the nearest neighbours of the nearest neighbours. Therefore div(grad(f(x,y)) is actually computed using (x,y) and x+2, x-2, y+2, y-2. Hence the difference.

The greater the grid spacing, the greater the discrepancy between these two calculations will be.

Comment: This is correct. I learned this myself but never came back to this question. So, you get the answer. :)

Comment: This is not correct. The gradient is computed using x and x+1. Repeated application makes this x, x+1 and x+2, which is only a shift of what `del2` does.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on the [documentation of del2](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/del2.html), it differs a factor of `1/4` with the [gradient](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/gradient.html) method you compared it with.

This partly explains that factor 4 in your example.
I blame the rest on edge effects :p

Comment: Yes or the rest may be checkerboarding because the test field is so low-res. Just thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: @GuntherStryuf Hi all . I was going through this question because I am stuck in a similar problem. Is the laplacian operator as defined by Matlab really correct ? Shouldn't it be that the divergence of a gradient of a vector is equal to the Laplacian ? Why does MATLAB do extrapolation at the edges ?

Comment: 1. As they put it in their documentation, it looks correct to me. 2. `div(gradient(F(X))) == laplacian(F(X))´ so yes indeed, isn't it in the matlab implementation? haven't used it actually. I suggest you do some tests to see what suits your needs. 3. Extrapolation at the edges is imo done for keeping the same vector size

Comment: There is likely also a shift of one sample in the two results!