# making gradient and del2 in matlab even faster

Tags: matlab, optimization, image-processing, matrix

I have a few questions. Bear with me please. I wrote down a program and am trying to optimize it. I am posting only the code snippets that I believe that can be further optimized.

**1.** First of all I am trying to calculate the gradient of an image. I previously used the **gradient operator** of the MATLAB but found it to be slow. So I wrote down my own code. Please find my code at [my gradient code here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958231/fast-computation-of-a-gradient-of-an-image-in-matlab)

I ran the profiler on MATLAB and found that my program still had a few bottlenecks. I am posting an image here : 
[image: gradient profile]

As you can see I am using two extra matrices A and B two times each for the calculation of the gradient in the horizontal & vertical direction. Is it really necessary ? Can't the operation be integrated in line 5 & line 8 without the use of extra matrices A & B. Will the removal of the extra matrices A & B make **my code run faster ?**

**2.** Secondly I needed to use the Laplacian operator in my code and found it to be one of the bottlenecks of my program. I have already read the matlab documentation & also read the links [Discrepancy between Matlab del2 and Matlab gradient of gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353087/discrepancy-between-matlab-del2-and-matlab-gradient-of-gradient) and [Understanding DEL2 function in Matlab in order to code it in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342651/understanding-del2-function-in-matlab-in-order-to-code-it-in-c).

I then checked the profile of del2 and found this. [image]. My question is this what are the functions of the children function **parse_inputs** and **ipermute** in this case ? 
It is to be noted that I am working with an image matrix whose size will always be greater than 64X64.

I read the explanation for permute and it said that "**Permute so that the del2 is always taken along the columns.**". What does it mean actually ? I read somewhere that MATLAB uses column major format . Could anyone please explain what it means ?

Regarding the parse_inputs sub-function  I read the explanation where it stated that

```
 %PARSE_INPUTS
                  %   [ERR,F,LOC,CFLAG] = PARSE_INPUTS(F,V) returns the spacing LOC
                  %   along the x,y,z,... directions and a column vector flag CFLAG. ERR
                  %   will be true if there is an error.
```

I have no idea what this function does. Please can anyone explain ?

**3**. I also tried to write down my own del2 function for matlab so as to make it faster but strangely I could only cope with the interior points. Is the implementation in MATLAB correct for del2 ? Why does it do extrapolation at the boundary points ?

Should not the basis of the Laplacian operator be always that it should hold the equality ?

```
laplacian = del2(image);

[x, y] = gradient(image);
[xx, xy] = gradient(x);
[yx, yy] = gradient(y);
laplacian = xx + yy;
```

This code was taken from [Please check code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353087/discrepancy-between-matlab-del2-and-matlab-gradient-of-gradient). I read all the posts there but the explanation did not satisfy me. Please could you explain why the above code does not give the same output ?

Thanks everyone for reading this long and boring set of questions. Any help will be greatly appreciated. If anyone has a problem I will split the questions and post it separately. Just say so guys!

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :** After slogging through the whole day finally managed to remove the *offending* matrices A & B. I am writing down the code below :

```
function [dx dy] = gradient_my_code(I)
dx=[I(:,2)-I(:,1) (I(:,3:end)-I(:,1:end-2))./2 I(:,end)-I(:,end-1)];
dy=[I(2,:)-I(1,:) ; (I(3:end,:)-I(1:end-2,:))./2 ; I(end,:)-I(end-1,:)];
```

For **timing purposes** I did this :

```
xaxis = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000];
n1 = zeros(1,length(xaxis));
n2 = zeros(1,length(xaxis));
for i=1:length(xaxis);
    x=xaxis(i);
    u=magic(x);
    tic
    [dx dy] = gradient(u);
    n1(i)=toc;
    tic
    [dx dy] = gradient_my_code(u);
    n2(i)=toc;
end
plot(n1,'r','LineWidth',3);
hold on;
plot(n2,'b','LineWidth',3);
hold off;
```

[image: Speed comparison between gradient of matlab and my code]

And I plotted the speed comparison . Please check and guys give your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the large number of questions I attempt to summarize:

(1) Matlab is *highly* optimized, so it is unlikely that you can beat the native routines written by the people at Mathworks based on extensive numerical research. As a caveat, because the Mathworks code often performs error, data type, and dimensionality checking on inputs, you can save some time during execution by writing code that does not perform those tasks, but I don't recommend that unless you have a very good reason to do so. You can also write `mex` functions which can (but I can't verify this) save some time on execution if you have a large project.

(2) Matlab routines are generally written to process arrays columnwise (since the routines are written to take advantage of columnwise data storage). If you read the code behind function `gradient` you'll find, for instance, that one of the steps is to "permute so that the gradient is always taken along the columns."

(3) I recommend you look at the code behind `del2` (with `edit del2`) and `gradient` to understand why computing the Laplacian as `del2` versus `xx+yy` as in your code would be different. It has to do with different finite difference approximations for continuous 1st vs 2nd derivatives.

As far as the behavior of `del2` at the edges, it turns out that one step in the algorithm is to "linearly extrapolate second differences from interior". It's simply a way of obtaining an approximation of the Laplacian for all of the points in the input array, including at the edges where only a single-sided approx is possible.

Finally, on `parse_inputs`: this is just a function that takes care of assigning values to all of the variables used in the gradient computation, using either user input or defaults as the case may be.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Regarding your answer (1) I do know that MATLAB writes good optimized code. However the gradient function that I wrote down seems to be many times faster atleast 50% for arrays upto size 4000X4000 I did not check any further. Also the output is correct. I simply wanted to rework the code so as not to use the extra matrices A & B. However finally solved it! Please see my edit!

Comment: Regarding your (2) answer please could you tell me what does the function parse_inputs do ? I found this sub-function in many places ... and want to know about it more ... There is not even a help file associated with it.

Comment: Please can you check my code and give your thoughts. My code works atleast 50% faster. So I did no check on errors though. So is it a correct approach ?

Comment: @roni That is an interesting result. I'll take your word for it and attempt the computations when I have some more time :). If you look at function `gradient`, there is some overhead (as I mentioned) in parsing the input, applying permutations as necessary, and, I think most importantly (but have not verified!) dividing the differences by a *step size*, something you do not do. Since division is costly, I am not surprised if your routine, which basically removes all of the aforementioned steps, is faster. The factor of 2 is however somewhat impressive.

Comment: @roni On the other hand, if you are serious about performance and not just getting practice with different algorithms, follow the advice provided to your previous question and use the routines accompanying the image processing toolbox (if you have it) or look at similar routines at matlab central. Those are optimized (using compiled mex routines) for heavy duty processing of large datasets.

Comment: Thanks for your observations. Please do give me your comments when you get the time to check my computations. Yes I removed several overhead because they were not required in my work and tried to optimize it to the maximum potential. Actually I do not  know C# much otherwise I would have tried to write the MEX file myself. I keep on hearing MEX files are faster. Can you tell me the basic reason for it ? Thanks for your replies by the way :)

Comment: @roni I checked your computations, the result is as you report. I was actually surprised to see that modifying the code in `gradient` - in particular I/O handling, had a large effect on the time. The main effect was due to division by a step size array, as I mentioned. I don't have the profiler to check the effect of these changes in detail without a large investment in time. Your code for computation of the gradient looks fine however. Keep in mind that you lack a step size.

Comment: BTW if this answered your question feel free to click on the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: @Try Hard I just wanted to let you know that I have seen a few instances where custom code is faster than Matlab's defaults.  The cases are usually specialized, but not uncommon.  A great example is using fft->multiply->ifft instead of conv.  And the reason why compiled code is (sometimes) faster is because a compiler tries to reorganize/rewrite your code to improve performance using a defined set of rules.  Though, even when scripting, Matlab has a "Just In Time" compiler that's supposed to do some degree of optimization of your script before running it.

Comment: @TTT could you post me the link for the fft->multiply->ifft instead of conv ? I need to use 2-D convolution and am presently trying to use 2 separable filters in 1 dimesion. The code becomes faster but I would like to check whether it can be made more fast ?

Comment: @TryHard Hi again. I believe you posted a link for parse_inputs but then edited the answer. Please could you repost the link so I may have a lookee

Comment: @TTT check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570453/2d-convolution-by-1d-convolution-using-separable-properties for my post on separable filters

Comment: @roni that link was to the documentation on the input parser class, but it turns out `gradient` does not use it. In any case the link is http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/inputparserclass.html;jsessionid=ab929125eacb378647cff123a3e4

Comment: @TryHard Thanks again for the link. Yes the gradient does not use it but del2 does. I am trying to rewrite my own code for del2.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Jan Simon's [DGradient](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29887-dgradient) MEX function. It is 10-20 times faster than ***gradient*** and provides the same results. You can then modify its source code for a similar improvement to the ***del2*** performance.

This is indeed a rare example where a Mex file outperforms a native Matlab function by such a significant speedup.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will try it out and let u know. Actually I do not know how to run a MEX function in matlab. I am using a windows 7 64 bit OS and do not have C/C++ installed. That's why I was searching for inbuilt matlab command .....Anyway could u give any suggestions for improving the del2 performance ?